# Permutation and Combination Advanced with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In a local police station, a different combination of three constables is selected daily for duty. If there are ten constables available and the system operates every day except Sunday, how many weeks will go by before the same three constables are on duty again together?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos this was my first question, I will give additional information in my next question. I know how to solve this question which was explained by user8734617

Answer (score 1):

Three out of ten constables can be chosen in ${10\choose 3}=120$ ways. To go through all those combinations, it will take $120/6=20$ weeks (with $6$ working days per week).

Comment: Your answer is correct, but can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @nitishGupta_1729 I need to know what I can assume that you know to start with. For example, are you familiar with "$n$ choose $k$", $nCk$ or $n\choose k$ notation? Do you know what "combinations" are and how to calculate their number?

Comment: I later thought about it again and understood how you solved the question.